# Create provisioning profile for apple built in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

Im trying to deploy an IOS app developed on flutter but im with this error and I can't find any solution that solve this problem. Can someone help me?

The error that appears on flutter is this, when I try to build:

"Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'com.example.cfca' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App
Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.cfca'. Automatic signing is disabled and
unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to
xcodebuild.

It appears that there was a problem signing your application prior to installation on the device.

Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Also try selecting 'Product > Build' to fix the problem.
Encountered error while building for device."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhJdq.png)

Comment: Please post your code and errors as text

Comment: You can't create a provisioning profile with the example domain in the bundleId is because it's something very common, change it to something like `com.{younickname}.{nameproject}`. Example: `com.devsolu.calendarapp`. The bundleId has to be something unique.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried that, but it didn't worked. Still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is adding a device on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles". This is only for those that didn't test the app on real device, throw XCode. In my case, since I don't have an IPhone, I asked someone with IPhone to send me the Device ID (UDID) from that phone and added on Apple Development portal. This is the solution that I recommend for those that don't want to by an IPhone.